# Intelliguard, the YGuard based Obfuscation plugin for IntelliJ, seems totally awesome, but fails to work, and gives "Icon cannot be found" error

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, obfuscation, intellij-plugin, yguard

Intelliguard, the YGuard based Obfuscation plugin for IntelliJ, seems totally awesome, but fails to work, and gives "Icon cannot be found" error.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4511?pr=idea

https://code.google.com/p/intelliguard/

After installing the Intelliguard Plugin, it is awesome all the way, then at the very last step of the configuration steps, there is an Error:

```
Icon cannot be found in '/nodes/ModuleClosed.png', aClass='class com.github.intelliguard.ui.JarOptionsForm'
```

There is some material on this error:
https://github.com/ronniekk/intelliguard/issues/1

That material, at the bottom, mentions the newest commit, and one guy was able to create a working plugin.jar with it.

Newest Commit:

https://github.com/olehrgf/intelliguard/tree/IntellijIdea13.1

This seems to be a GREAT solution to current obfuscators, because it is free and ALL the configurations are perfectly handled with a very simple to use GUI.

Any help in getting it to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "with the Main Class selected"? There is no main class in an IntelliJ IDEA plugin. You need to use a run configuration of type "Plugin" to run a plugin.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html

Comment: and no, you don't need to touch Edit Configuration > Defaults. you need to create a new run configuration.

Comment: I deleted some comments, thanks.